# why use do {...} while(0) macro for one-statment body?

Tags: c, macros, do-while

I read this in `include/linux/sched.h`:

```
#define __set_task_state(tsk, state_value)              \
    do { (tsk)->state = (state_value); } while (0)
```

I know that when it comes to multi-statement in a body, a `do {...} while (0)` should be used. But that is just one statement in the body, is it really necessary to use `do {...} while (0)`? How about just as follows:

```
#define __set_task_state(tsk, state_value)              \
    ((tsk)->state = (state_value))
```

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm asking about one-statement body, is it involved in that topic?

Comment: Yes; have you looked at it?

Comment: @trojanfoe Would you please let me know the specific part or the answer concerning one-statement body? I looked at the answers again and still didn't get it. Thank you.

Comment: You're correct, it doesn't have any answers about any single statement bodies.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean; apologies. I think you'll probably find that `do { ... } while(0)` is being used in the linux headers regardless of the number of statements within the "loop".  This makes it easy to change to two-or-more statements later.

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok, I get it. Thank you for answering. Should my topic still be duplicate? Or change it to normal so that other people won't skip or miss something here.

Comment: It's should not be a duplicate, however you need to flag for moderator attention to make that happen, sorry.  My comment is also incorrect as I've just checked the linux kernel coding conventions and `do/while` is only mentioned when multiple statements are used within a macro.

Comment: Sheesh.  Hey, black, Vasfed, and Basile Starynkevitch: He's already explained that it's *not* a duplicate.  The linked questions don't answer the sub-question, "Why would you use this technique for the body of a single-statement macro?"  AIUI, the question has already been closed, and reopened, once already, and now you guys closed it again.  Double Jeopardy!

Answer (score 1):

It's true that when the body of the macro is a single statement or expression (as here), the use of the `do { ... } while(0)` trick is less compelling.  There's not nearly as much wrong with

```
#define __set_task_state(tsk, state_value)              \
    ((tsk)->state = (state_value))
```

But I suspect we could still come up with cases where this "simpler" definition might cause problems, such that the do/while trick would still be advantageous.  For example, if you accidentally wrote

```
__set_task_state(a, b)
do_something_else;
```

the error message you'd get for the missing semicolon might be less confusing in the do/while case.  (Or not.)

In general, of course, function-like macros are often problematic, and inline functions are recommended.  I can't say why an inline function wasn't used here.  (There are certainly plenty of them elsewhere in the Linux kernel sources.)